# axml does not load in older compiling version in VS2017

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I'm using VS2017 for development with Xamarin Android native apps.

I get following error in the xaml designer when I set *Compile using Android version* property to Android 4.4 (Kit Kat)

[image]

Full Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mono.android.DesignerException.fromThrowable(DesignerException.java:30)
    at mono.android.DesignerSession.checkRenderResultForError(DesignerSession.java:177)
    at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:228)
    at mono.android.DesignerSession.processMessage(DesignerSession.java:693)
    at mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
    at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When I set *Compile using Android version* property to Android 5.0 (Lollipop) everything works fine.

What is the problem I'm running into?

Comment: Add the code that is actually throwing the Exception and please do not use images for errors as the full error can not be seen and it is not searchable, add the Exception/stacktrace text directly to your question. I would *assume* that the error is due to your code using a class and/or method/property that was added in API 5.0+ and thus it is not available in the order APIs but without the code and the full exception that is just a guess...

Comment: I added full exception message. I get this exception also in new default project.

Comment: Do you actually have that SDK version downloaded? Or do you just have the emulator? If it's related to the designer, it has nothing to do with using a feature in an older/newer version on Android, I suspect you're missing something related to the Android SDK for that version.

Comment: I have installed Android SDK Tools (25.2.5), Android SDK Build-tools (25.0.3), SDK Platform for API 25, 23, 21, 19 And 18. I have installed for Android 4.4.2 (API 19) this features: SDK Platform, ARM EABI v7a System Image, Intel x86 Atom System image and Google APIs. Did I forget something to install?

Comment: It looks like a bug has been entered for this issue, it seems like quite a few people are having the same problem (I am one) https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=57406